# Poisson regression on Lung Cancer

Tags: regression, modeling, poisson-distribution

I am a statistic student and I'm trying to study the effects of smoking on lung cancer rates.

Below you will find what I did.  My question is about the homoskedasticity, I think that the assumption is not valid.  What can I do about that? I have to estimate a new model?

Then in model 3 I combine "smokes cigars or pipe only" with "doesn't smoke" because that level wasn't significant in the model, is it right?

The dataset is provided at this website "http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/datasets/#smoking".  The variable smoke is:

```r
smoking status: coded 1 = doesn't smoke, 2 = smokes cigars or pipe only, 3 = smokes cigarrettes and cigar or pipe, and 4 = smokes cigarrettes only

lungcancer=read.table("SMOKEdata2.txt", header=T)

#Check reference category
str(lungcancer)
lungcancer$smoke=relevel(lungcancer$smoke, ref="no")

lungcancer$prop<-lungcancer$dead/lungcancer$pop  #Rate dead/pop
lungcancer$age_cont=as.integer(lungcancer$age) #age as a continuous variable

#STEP 1: MODEL

#MODEL 1: COMPLETE WITH INTERACTION
lungcancer$age_sq=lungcancer$age_cont^2 #Because is not linear
mod1=glm(dead~1+age_cont+age_sq+smoke+smoke:age_cont, data=lungcancer,offset=log(pop), family=poisson))
summary(mod1)

#STEP 2: Hp TEST
#MODEL 2
mod2=(glm(dead~1+age_cont+age_sq+smoke, data=lungcancer,offset=log(pop), family=poisson))
summary(mod2)
anova(mod2,mod1, test="Chisq")


#MODEL 3
lungcancer$type_smoke=lungcancer$smoke
lungcancer$type_smoke[lungcancer$type=="cigarPipeOnly"]="no"
mod3=glm(dead~1+age_cont+age_sq+type_smoke+type_smoke:age_cont, data=lungcancer,offset=log(pop), family=poisson)
summary(mod3)
lrtest(mod3,mod1) 


#STEP 4: DIAGNOSTIC
#Residuals analysis

#DEVIANCE
pvalue<-1-pchisq(deviance(mod2),mod2$df.residual)

#Pearson
pearson.res<-resid(mod2, type="pearson")
pearson<-sum(pearson.res^2)
pvalue.pea<-1-pchisq(pearson, mod2$df.residual)

#homoskedasticity
deviance.res=resid(mod2, type="deviance")
y.fit=fitted.values(mod2)
plot(y.fit, deviance.res, ylim=c(-3,3))
abline(h=mean(deviance.res))
abline(h=1.96, col=2); abline(h=-1.96, col=2)
```

Comment: A Poisson glm doesn't assume homoskedacity. In fact it assumes something quite the opposite: that the (conditional) mean and variance are directly proportional.

Comment: @deasmhumnha is correct that Poisson regression does not assume homoskedasticity. Marica Usually only Linear Regression makes that assumption. One idea is to try Negative-Binomial regression instead of Poisson. Negative-Binomial regression estimates separate mean and variance parameters, so that could be what you are looking for. There are other things you could do to try and control for unequal variance--such as penalizing the likelihood--but I don't think you have enough variables for that.